# Set session expire time only for some sessions

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm having more than one session in my application. I know how to set expire time for all sessions but I want to set expire time only for a particular session not all sessions. Is it possible?

Answer (score -1):

```
if(!isset($_SESSION)) session_start(); // start session if was not start.

$_SESSION['expire_time'] = time()+(60*15); //set expire for 15 minutes

if(isset($_SESSION['expire_time']) && $_SESSION['expire_time'] < time())
   // user session is expired
else
  // user session is valid
```